# Whether all the bits are off in a data structure?

Tags: c++

This is my first attempt at generic programming. I'm making a binary tree template class and I'm at the point where I add an element to the tree:

```
void BinaryTree<T>::add(T newElement) { ... }
```

This of course will involve a `while` loop that right-shifts `newElement`'s bits until they're all off. But how do I generically check whether they're all off? I know that in the case of `ints` and `chars` I'd be checking them against `0` and `'\O'`, respectively. But my algorithm needs to work for any data structure's equivalent of "zero", if that makes sense. What is the C++ purist's way of doing this?

Comment: "This of course will involve a while loop that right-shifts newElement's bits until they're all off." - huh? what? why?

Comment: Seems you somehow misunderstood what a binary tree is. Probably, you can try to tell us how to right shift an integer/char value for a binary tree in your mind? Then we can tell you what's wrong with your understanding of binary tree.

Comment: I concur with @user534498, you seem to have an incorrect understanding of binary trees.

Comment: In a binary tree, each node holds a value.  To traverse the tree you take the left branch when (newElement < node->element) and the right branch otherwise.  The while loop changes node until you reach a leaf of the tree.  To add() you traverse the tree and add newElement as a child of the last node the traverse visits.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of an oddly worded question, but (if I understood it correctly) can't you just cast the value in question to a boolean?

```
if (!(bool)newElement) std::cout << "value equal to zero." << std::endl;
```